# Using PowerShell to reformat phone number

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Tried running this code in PowerShell and C#. Even if I run the code interactively I can see the phone number get reset back to the original value in my copy of the list item. Do you know why it isn't saving or keeping the changes we try to make?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

. $PSScriptRoot/../


$listName = 'Vendor Referral List'  # The internal (or original) name of the list
$fieldName = 'WorkPhone' # The internal (or original) name of the field

$context = Get-****Context 'https://****sharepoint'

# used this to help hunt down the InternalName of the field
# $fieldNames = Get-****ListFields $context $listName

Write-Host ('Getting items from list: ' + $masterListName)
$allitems = Get-****ListItems $context $listName


# a crazy regular expression to find numbers and ignore garbage
$pattern = '^(1?[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4}).*)$'

$counter = 0
foreach($item in $allitems)
{
  $phoneNumber = $item.FieldValues[$fieldName]

  if($phoneNumber -match $pattern) 
  {
    $counter += 1
    $phoneNumber = ('(' + $matches[2] + ') ' + $matches[3] + '-' + $matches[4])
    $item.FieldValues[$fieldName] = $phoneNumber
    $item.Update()
    # $context.Load($item)
  }
  elseif($phoneNumber -ne '')
  {
    Write-Host ('Non-matching: ' + $phoneNumber)
    $item.FieldValues[$fieldName] = ''
    $item.Update()
    # $context.Load($item)
  }


  # process in batches nicely to avoid API throttling
  #if($counter % 300 -eq 0)
  #{
    Write-Host ($counter.ToString() + ' records updated. Saving changes')
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    sleep 1
  #}
}

# save the last batch
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$context.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FieldValues` is a `get` only property which means you can only read the properties but not to set the properties.

You need to change the logic as follows

```
$phoneNumber = ('(' + $matches[2] + ') ' + $matches[3] + '-' + $matches[4])
$item[$fieldName] = $phoneNumber
$item.Update()
```

[Refer the FieldValues member in the ListItem object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.fieldvalues.aspx)